# Difference between Job Scheduling in the Grid and in the Cloud Computing

Tags: cloud, scheduling, jobs

My question may sound strange but recently I am reading about Cloud computing and the similarities are very blur especially Job Scheduling. Can all Job Scheduling algorithms from the Grid be applied to a Cloud environment?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, That depends on the algorithm.

a lot of research and projects try to find whether grid algorithms can be applied to cloud computing with the same behavior or not. So, I think my answer if it's not complete, then it answer the 'all Job Scheduling algorithms from the Grid' part of your question.